# My Maps - Error occurred when uploading kml or gpx file

Tags: gps, trace, kml, gpx, mymaps

In My Maps, when importing gpx or kml file, My Maps says that an error occurred. Can not load gps trace

I want to upload the gpx file of a trecking in Corse, France, it is called « Mare I mare centre » in a format gpx or kml it doesn’t work

Comment: could you please give us slightly more context how you do this and are you sure your files are not corrupted?

Comment: The files are not corrupted, they are on a clean web site of trekking well known : alltrails

Comment: Can you think of any other inforamtion you can provide us with so that can the community can help and resolve the issue for you?

Comment: No nothing more

Comment: have you tried what @Voytas describe? or maybe this: https://droidwin.com/cannot-upload-kml-and-kmz-files-to-google-my-maps-fix/

Answer (score 0):

The same problem. But only if I try import file from your hard drive. My maps cannot import any file (I tried gpx, kml, csv) from few different sources. Previous working files doesn't work now. This start happening few days ago.

BUT if I first upload file to Google Drive and then try import from this one it works. In the dialog box "Choose file to import" on top is button Google Drive.

So it seems to be a problem with uploading file process on Google side.